# Stop loss = 100 pips

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Can someone help me to set stop loss = 100 pips to this strategy? I have no idea how to do it

```
//@version=5
strategy("MovingAvg2Line Cross", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(9)
slowLength = input(18)
price = close
mafast = ta.sma(price, fastLength)
maslow = ta.sma(price, slowLength)
if (ta.crossover(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossLE", strategy.long, comment="MA2CrossLE")
if (ta.crossunder(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossSE", strategy.short, comment="MA2CrossSE")
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

If someone can write for me code of stop loss i would be grateful

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `loss` parameter in the `strategy.exit()` function sets a stop loss order in measured in ticks.

I've added a short function to calculate [ticks vs pips](https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/pip-size-instrument/) and then set the value of its return as the `loss` argument.

```
//@version=5
strategy("MovingAvg2Line Cross", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(9)
slowLength = input(18)

GetPipSize(size) =>
    syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1) * size

price = close
mafast = ta.sma(price, fastLength)
maslow = ta.sma(price, slowLength)
if (ta.crossover(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossLE", strategy.long, comment="MA2CrossLE")
    // Add a 100 pip stop loss to the long entry
    strategy.exit("MA2CrossXL", "MA2CrossLE", loss=GetPipSize(100))
if (ta.crossunder(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossSE", strategy.short, comment="MA2CrossSE")
    // Add a 100 pip stop loss to the short entry
    strategy.exit("MA2CrossXS", "MA2CrossSE",loss=GetPipSize(100))
```